# What is the difference between the phrases "as far as I know" and "for all I know"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in the sentences with those phrases below.

> There could be billions of the planets like the Earth for all I know.
>
> There could be billions of the planets like the Earth as far as I know.

I have checked a few dictionaries, but still cannot see the difference.

Comment: as far as I know means you know something about it. For all I know means: it could be that [something is true or not true].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**For all I know**" is often used in situations where the statement that you are qualifying with this phrase runs completely contrary to what was said right before that, or is a wild guess that would change everything compared to what was said before.

> I don't know why his opinion of these products is so favorable. He could be an investor in the company that produces them, **for all I know.**

StoneyB has given a rather comprehensive answer on "for all I know" [on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/92216/278584).

"**As far as I know**" is not used alongside guesses. It means that you are offering information that is based on what you actually know, but you don't know a lot, or you could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

**For all I know.** People typically say this when they think they know very little or nothing about a subject. (They have no expertise at all.)

**As far as I know.** People typically say this when they know at least a little bit about something and may even be true experts in the field, but are granting that no one ever knows everything.